# Margin issue w/ Android layouts (ScrollView & Linear)

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, margin, android-scrollview

The issue:

I am attempting to remove the space between the images/views so that it looks as if the background is actually one image.  Different approaches or a way to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Example Image :
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#edeab5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgnewsfeedtop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/newsfeedtop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgnewsfeedleft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/newsfeedleft" />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:src="@drawable/newsfeedbg" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn1_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn2_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn3_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn4_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn5_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn6_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn7_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/filler" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgnewsfeedright"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/newsfeedright" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgnewsfeedbot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/newsfeedbot" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager2"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager3"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager2"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager3"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT****

After help was provided, revised code and image:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#edeab5" >


   <View
        android:id="@+id/newstop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newsfeedtop"
        />

   <View
        android:id="@+id/newsleft"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newsfeedleft"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newstop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newsbottom"
        />

   <View
        android:id="@+id/newsleft"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newsfeedright"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newstop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newsbottom"
        />


   <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newstop">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cc0000" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn1_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn2_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn3_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn2_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn4_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn3_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn5_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn4_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


            </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>

   <View
        android:id="@+id/newsbottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newsfeedbot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroller"
        />

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonsrow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newsbottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager2"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager3"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

</LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/buttonsrow2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="75dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsrow1"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager2"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager3"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_house_manager4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btnhousemanager"  />

</LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already done something with relative layouts?

This is how I would solve this.
You give every view an id by

```
android:id = "@+id/whateveryouwanttonameit"
```

and then you can align other views by reffering to this ids.

For example:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
    android:text="@string/newGameButton"
    android:background="@drawable/newgame"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/newGameButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/newGameButton"
    android:src="@drawable/x"
    android:id="@+id/sp2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"/>
```

in this example the ImageViews Left edge gets aligned with the left edge of the ImageButton by using:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/newGameButton"
```

It is also exactly above the newGameButton without any space between by adding

```
android:align_above="@id/newGameButton"
```

This way you can build your whole activity layout.

So here is the example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >


   <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_above="@id/scroller"
        />


   <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#000000">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FF00" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn1_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn2_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn3_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn2_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn4_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn3_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn5_news_feed"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn4_news_feed"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


            </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>


   </RelativeLayout>
```

gives me this layout:

[image: layout]

i kept the margin attribute and made the background of the scrollview in green.

With the below attribute I made the layout.

And just for showing you that there is no space in between to elements if you not define it I added a red View Element without a margin attribute.

I havent done the whole layout for you but just copied some of it to show how you can do it with a RelativeLayout. I hope this works out for you ;)

Comment: Hmm.. This seems like a nice way to assemble the box that contains the ScrollView, but is positioning a ScrollView within a RelativeLayout going to be a problem?  I'll mess around with this, and if I can get it to work I'll "accept" your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I reread your question and I just thought to complicate. Just delete the Margins in your red frame views.

Comment: Made the modifications you suggested. Works like a charm! Thanks for the help (my revised layout && image is [will be] posted).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about that black lines? I don't think I understood well your question...

You are doing in your "manual listview" (I mean: instead of using a scrollview and a linearlayout you should use a listview and a custom adapter to add N newsfeeds):

```
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

This sets right, left, top, bottom margins. Do this instead:

```
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
```

Comment: The black lines are part of the ScrollView. I was talking about the margin between the red box that contains the black lines.  There is spacing between the topbar and the sidebars that I would like gone, as well as between the sidebars and the bottom bar.